# Update table, set ID based on relation. Column not found

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I have the following update statement, but it says `[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'b.user_id' in 'on clause'`

```
UPDATE brands b set b.workspace_id = (
  SELECT w.id from workspaces w
    INNER JOIN users u on b.user_id = u.id
    inner join team_members tm on u.id = tm.user_id
    inner join teams t on tm.team_id = t.id AND w.id = t.workspace_id
);
```

Basically, there are `brands` and `workspaces`. A new column `workspace_id` was added as foreign key, and the workspace id can be found through the relation `brand -> has user_id -> user has team -> team has workspace_id`

In a programming side I could find first all workspaces to process, then get all user ids for that workspace, then run a `update brands b set workspace_id = :wsId where user_id in (:userIds)`

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table brands
(
    id           bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id      int unsigned                  not null,
    name         varchar(100)                  null,
    workspace_id int                           null
)
```

Comment: The error message could not be any more clear.  The `brands` table does not have a `user_id` column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but it does

Comment: The join condition `on b.user_id = u.id` makes no sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you use the parent row on a update subquery?

Comment: Perhabs it would help when you provide the create table definition which you have shown for the brands table also for the other affected tables.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` report? I can reproduce your error in [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEWpDqWaN5rUR6mSDyP6W9/0), which is using MySQL 8.0.12, but the error does not occur when I test on my local computer, using MySQL 8.0.28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the column from brands in a join condition, but you can use it in a where condition in the sub-query

> ```
> create table brands (
>   workspace_id int,
>   user_id int
>   );
> create table users (
>   id int);
> create table team_members(
>   user_id int,
>   team_id int
>   );
> create table teams (
>   id int,
>   workspace_id int
>   );
> create table workspaces(
>   user_id int,
>   id int
>   );
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE brands set workspace_id = (
>   SELECT w.id from workspaces w
>     INNER JOIN users u on w.user_id = u.id
>     inner join team_members tm on u.id = tm.user_id
>     inner join teams t on tm.team_id = t.id AND w.id = t.workspace_id
>     WHERE brands.user_id = u.id
> );
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=207f238a6909867f88ed6b55dc5ce5cc)*

Comment: Thanks! The relations are a bit different but your answer guided me